# How to check current User has permission from everyone group programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2016, check-permissions

I want to check whether current user has permissions from everyone group or not, using CSOM.
any leads please.

Comment: any updates?  I am curious about the same thing

Comment: @Anthony I don't have a proper solution for this problem but I have found out a way through which we can confirm whether user is added from everyone or not. I will update the answer after testing the code.